# How to defend against xss when saving data and when displaying it

Tags: java, html, jsp, security, esapi

Let's say I have a simple CRUD application with a form to add new object and edit an existing one. From a security point of view I want to defend against cross-site scripting. Fist I would validate the input of submitted data on the server. But after that, I would escape the values being displayed in the view because maybe I have more than one application writing in my database (some developer by mistake inserts unvalidated data in the DB in the future). So I will have this jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="esapi" uri="http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API" %>
<form ...>
   <input name="myField" value="<esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute>${myField}</esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute>" />
</form>
```

`<esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute>` does almost the same thing as `<c:out>`, it HTML escapes sensitive characters like `< > "` etc

Now, if I load an object that somehow was saved in the database with `myfield=abc<def` the input will display correctly the value `abc<def` while the value in the html behind will be `abc&lt;def`.

**The problem is** when the user submits this form without changing the values, the server receives the value `abc&lt;def` instead of what is visible in the page `abc<def`. So this is not correct. How should I implement the protection in this case?

Comment: "the server receives the value `abc&lt;def`" Why is this a problem? The value is already escaped, so you don't have to do anything. You can insert that directly to your database.

Comment: @Michael you want to save the original data.  The two-pronged approach is:  validate on input, escape on output.

Comment: And store the *original* data

Comment: Storing modified data as @Michael suggests is dangerous.  Always submit RAW data to the server (under your control) and *distrust* everything received from the client.

Comment: @avgvstvs What I mean is, you can *attempt* to re-escape the re-submitted string `abc&lt;def` but as there is nothing to escape, the operation will do nothing.

Comment: @Michael Well actually, you should see  `abc&lt;def` transformed into ` abc&&lt;def` if you escape it again.  My comment was more that `abc&lt;def`should be *canonicalized* (reduced to its lowest common form) *prior* to any processing operations against it.  You shouldn't be validating against a string that contains HTML, you should be validating against raw text.  At the server, `abc&lt;def` should be `abc<def`.  See ESAPI-Java's reference validator implementation.  (I'm co-lead on that project.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is when the user submits this form without changing the values, the server receives the value  `abc&lt;def` instead of what is visible in the page abc

Easy.  In this case HTML decode the value, and then validate.

Though as noted in a few comments, you should see how we operate with the OWASP [ESAPI-Java project](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultValidator.java).  By default we always canonicalize the data which means we run a series of decoders to detect multiple/mixed encoding as well as to create a string safe to validate against with regex.

For the part that really guarantees you protection however, you normally want to have raw text stored on the server--not anything that contains HTML characters, so you *may* wish to store the unescaped string, if only that you can safely encode it when you send it back to the user.

Encoding is the *best* protection for XSS, and I would in fact recommend it BEFORE input validation if for some reason you had to choose.

I say *may* because in general I think its a bad practice to store altered data.  It can make troubleshooting a chore. This can be even more complicated if you're using a technology like TinyMCE, a rich-text editor in the browser.  It also renders html so its like dealing with a browser within a browser.

Comment: So you propose always un-escaping the input, on client-side or, even better, on server-side. That would mean some one could inject some html in the database if they type in my form some html escaped strings. For ex. `&lt;script&gt;doEvilJavaScript()...` would be persisted as `<script>doEvilJavaScript()...`. But then I can add validators server-side to white-list or at least black list some dangerous strings to detect such cases. You wouldn't be storing the original data in this particular case, however

Comment: See the reference validator implementation at the ESAPI-Java project.  By default we *canonicalize* input prior to validating, this is done both to detect attacks as well as to reduce the input down to its raw, interpreted-language free state.  You will want to process/validate against the canonicalized data, but store the raw form.

Comment: IN our case we attempt to decode the value with several codecs, but the first is always HTML in the reference implementation.

Comment: Updated answer to cover the full XSS protection:  Validate on input, escape on output.

Comment: It's important to note that all operations must be server-side to be considered safe.